# Grep http response in a perl object

Tags: perl, object

I have an http response in a perl object (HTTP::Tiny) that I'm trying to extract specific values from but a positive match returns the entire object instead of just the values I want. How can I just extract those lines or values I want from the object?

```
for my $url (@urls) {
print $url."\n";
$response = $http->get("$url");
my ($res) =  grep {/href/} $response->{content};
print $res;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` in Perl isn't quite like the command-line program of the same name. It works over arrays rather than text lines. Try something like this instead:

```
my ($res) =  grep {/href/} split(/\n/, $response->{content});
```

The `split` will turn the document you `GET` into an array of lines so that the `grep` will do what you expect.

Comment: Or since you discard all but the first match, `my ($res) = $response->{content} =~ /^(.*href.*)/m;`